# Query with empty entry

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, mono

I'm working on a catalog program and I use this piece of code to find resources on database:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Articoli WHERE CodiceArt='"+CodArtEntry.Text+"' OR Barcode='"+BarcodeEntry.Text+"' OR NomeArt LIKE '%"+NameArtEntry.Text+"%'";
```

This code works , but if NameArtEntry (GTK# Entry) is empty, it select every record of the database.

How can I avoid that ? Many thanks

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be concatenating strings to produce a query. Use `SqlCommand` instead, it will at least prevent the most common forms of SQL Injection. Take a look at http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Articoli WHERE CodiceArt='{0}' OR Barcode='{1}'", CodArtEntry.Text, BarcodeEntry.Text);
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NameArtEntry.Text))
     sql += String.Format(" OR NomeArt LIKE '%{0}%' ", NameArtEntry.Text);
```

Using String.Format will make your query more readable, particularly when you write direct sql

Answer (score 1):

Check for explicit empty values and ignore those.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Articoli WHERE CodiceArt is not null AND CodeArt <> '' and ( isCodiceArt='"+CodArtEntry.Text+"' OR Barcode='"+BarcodeEntry.Text+"' OR NomeArt LIKE '%"+NameArtEntry.Text+"%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your SQL-statement is vulnerable to [SQL-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You could always solve it by building your query in steps:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM Articoli WHERE CodiceArt='"+CodArtEntry.Text+"' OR barcode='"+BarcodeEntry.Text+"'";

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(NameArtEntry.Text)){
    query += " OR NomeArt LIKE '%"+NameArtEntry.Text + "%'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Articoli WHERE (CodiceArt='" + CodArtEntry.Text + "' OR Barcode='" + BarcodeEntry.Text + "' OR NomeArt LIKE '%" + NameArtEntry.Text + "%') AND NameArtEntry IS NOT NULL AND NameArtEntry <> ''";
```